# OpenLayers V3.19.1 doesn't show in JavaFX WebView

Tags: javafx, openlayers-3

I'm having trouble displaying a map with OpenLayers v3 in JavaFX's WebView. Here's my code:

**openLayersV3.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://openlayers.org/en/v3.19.1/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
<style>
.map {
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
}
</style>
<script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=requestAnimationFrame,Element.prototype.classList"></script>
<script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v3.19.1/build/ol.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
<title>OpenLayers 3 example</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
        function loadMap() {
            var map = new ol.Map({
                target: 'map',
                layers: [
                  new ol.layer.Tile({
                    source: new ol.source.OSM()
                  })
                ],
                view: new ol.View({
                  center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([10.0, 53.55]),
                  zoom: 10
                })
              });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onLoad="loadMap()">
    <h2>My Map</h2>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's an excerpt of the loader:

**OsmView.java**

```
...
protected WebView webView = new WebView();
protected WebEngine webEngine = webView.getEngine();

public OsmView() {
    final URL urlOsmMap = getClass().getResource("/some/package/name/openLayersV3.html");

    webEngine.load(urlOsmMap.toExternalForm());
    getChildren().add(webView);
}
...
```

When I load the html in a browser like IE or Firefox, it shows without any complications. But in the Java program, there is only a blank page with the h2 ("My Map"). But the JavaScript doesn't load. So, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Not sure if this is it, but make sure you have loaded all needed polyfills (requestAnimationFrame,Element.prototype.classList,URL)

Comment: @bartvde Ok, I added "URL" to the JavaScript import in the html, but it didn't work. How can I make sure I loaded them correctly?

Comment: I had the same problem. Polyfills would not return the correct content. I ended up tricking it into providing the correct code by using a false user-agent (I used chrome/10.0.0). That file loaded locally did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, actually I found a solution: the requestAnimationFrame is not found so you have to add the following lines before every other javascript stuff:

```
window.requestAnimFrame = (function(){
    return window.requestAnimationFrame ||
        window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
        function(callback, element) {
            window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
        };
})();
var requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimFrame;
```